# Select php e conexão com o banco- Iniciante

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um grande problema.. Sou iniciante com Php, já pesquisei muito mas não consigo prosseguir.

Está dando esse erro

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function mysqli_fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php**

Onde está o erro? Desculpe se for algo simples..

```
<?php
//Inicia página mudando a URL
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "    <title>Cliente</title>";
    echo "    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\">";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body>";

    //Conexão com o Banco
    $servidor = '1.1';
    $usuario = '**';
    $senha = '**';
    $banco = 'Organizacoes';
    // Conecta-se ao banco de dados MySQL
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
    // Caso algo tenha dado errado, exibe uma mensagem de erro
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());  

    // Conecta ao banco
    $mysqli = new mysqli('1.1', '**', '**', '**');

    // Executa uma consulta
    $sql = "SELECT 'id', 'nome' FROM Organizacoes LIMIT 5";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while ($dados = $query->mysqli_fetch_array()) {
    echo 'ID: ' . $dados['id'] . '';
    echo 'Nome: ' . $dados['nome'] . '';
}
    echo 'Registros encontrados: ' . $query->num_rows;

?>
```

Comment: Sua consulta falhou, tem erro de sintaxe, em nomes de tabelas ou campos se vão aspas, simplesmente remova elas.

Comment: Remover as aspas na parte do while?

Comment: `SELECT 'id', 'nome' FROM 'Instituicoes' LIMIT 5`, deve ficar apenas: `SELECT id, nome FROM Instituicoes LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 1):

O erro está nesta linha:

```
 // Executa uma consulta
$sql = "SELECT 'id', 'nome' FROM 'Instituicoes' LIMIT 5";
```

O correto seria

```
// Executa uma consulta
$sql = "SELECT 'id', 'nome' FROM Instituicoes LIMIT 5";
```

Sem aspas encapsulando o nome da tabela.

O erro que você mencionou diz que a função `mysqli_fetch_array()` estava tentando ser executada `on boolean`, ou seja a sua variável `$query` falhou e estava retornando false. A partir daí é só verificar o que pode ter falhado nela. Muitas vezes, é mai fácil verificar esse erro se você testar sua query direto no banco de dados e ver o que ele te retorna.

Comment: sugiro retirar as aspas inclusive do nome dos campos `SELECT id,nome FROM Instituicoes LIMIT 5`

Comment: Eu realmente não sei qual a implicação de deixar com ou sem aspas simples nos nomes de colunas durante o SELECT. No banco de dados que eu uso PostgreSQL, não há nenhum problema em deixar aspas simples encapsulando nomes de colunas.

Comment: Muita obrigada pelas orientações, de verdade.. Eu to usando workbench e aquele select rodou normalmente. Corrigi as aspas na tabela e deu esse erro: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_array() in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php on line 31

Será que tem algo errado nesse fetch_array?

Comment: Então retiro meu comentário, nos meus sistemas eu não uso aspas nesses casos, quando usava dava erro, mas mantenha o codigo de forma que funcione

Comment: Se  você deixar aspas simples em uma coluna, o resultado da sua consulta vai ter uma coluna com o valor que está entre as aspas. No postgres as apas duplas servem como escape caso o nome tenha acentos ou outros caracteres o equivalente no MySQL seria a crase.